# Не работает bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, django

Ребят, такая проблема. Не работает bootstrap.
Скачал с официального http://getbootstrap.com/ , распаковал себе в папку static. Прописал в settings путь для static. Беру стандартную страницу из примеров, копирую в свой шаблон, не работает и все тут. Не отображается никак, как будто вообще без него, лишь текст. Наведите на путь пожалуйста.

Comment: Не работает только bootstrap или любая статика?

показывайте что указали в settings, куда положили bootstrap и как вывели в шаблонах

Comment: Settings:

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

Шаблон:
http://pastebin.com/uqffze0E

Bootstrap положил в static

Comment: У тебя ж в шаблоне пути относительные. Сделай согласно документации https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Comment: Изменил на абсолютные. Все также.

Comment: Проблема решилась заменой в шаблоне {{ STATIC_URL }} на просто '/static/' .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В шаблоне нужно прописать пути к статике. Те что вы взяли из примеров - неправильные.

```
<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}bootstrap/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

только правильно пропишите путь к своему  css.

Comment: Изменил все так. К сожалению, все также.

Comment: Значит что-то у вас не правильно настроено или бутстрап лежит не там где нужно.

Как вы запускаете проект? через runserver?
Проверьте путь к css.
Попробуйте добраться до css просто открыв его URL в браузере.
Посмотрите в исходнике страницы путь, который сгенерировался в шаблоне.

Comment: Вот как сейчас выглядит шаблон http://pastebin.com/jVh7mGXt

Путь к css нормальный, запскаю runserver. Просто css открывается.

Comment: проверте в исходнике страницы сгенерированный путь

Comment: Прошу прощения, но как это сделать?

Comment: ctrl+alt+u в браузере

Comment: не работает такой хоткей в хроме и опере

Answer (score 0):

Вот добавишь настройку

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (

     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'bootstrap'), #сама папка указывается здесь
)
```

## обрати внимание в STATICFILES_DIRS у меня bootstrap папка называется

То есть я когда загружал папку так её и назвл.
Помещаешь её куда хочешь в проекте, лучше в папку static, но к этому мы придём
То есть берёшь папку со всеми файлами и просто вставляешь в проект.

А вот как выгядят настройки в html помести перед head 9а вообще похрен где, там мешать не будут и быстрее читаться.

```
<link href="{% static  'css/bootstrap.min.css'%}" rel="stylesheet">

 <script src="{% static "js/bootstrap.min.js"%}"></script>
```

Теперь обпати внимание, я говорил, что что у меня сам бутстрап находится в папке bootstrap, но как видишь здесь она не указывается.

1. Как вообще проверять пути.

   1. Копируешь сам путь. например css/bootstrap.min.css
   2. в manage.py запускаешь команду findstatic и вставляешь ( я пишу вставляешь потому что работаю в PyCharm), то что
      скопировал.
   3. Если путь верный. то напишет весь путь. если не верный то красный
      напишет не найден
   4. Всё работает твой бутстрап, да пути на сервере могут отличаться.

`Важно.` так как ты вставляешь тег `static` значит потом в `шаблоне в самом начале` добавляешь 
`{% load staticfiles %}` - для того, что бы работал тег static (не имеет ни какого отношения к папке static, почитай про теги)
Можно в базовый заложить, если пока не знаешь, то в каждый добавляй.

Да и на крайняк отпредли сразу эту настройку

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader'
)
```

Теперь когда получилось можно скопировать в папку static, добавив в настройку
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '`static`/bootstrap'), а с проекта удалить, будет работать быстрее

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    #os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/bootstrap'), 
)
```

Думаю принцип теперь понятен, я много раз скачивал разные проекты, у них всегда бутсрап отдельно идёт.

```
Валерий Бовсуновский
Обучение Python Django
http://pro365.net
```